# Função em java equivalente ao map() do c++

Tags: java, c++

Existe uma função para java, equivalente ao  [map()](http://renatoaloi.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/funcao-map-do-arduino.html) do c++?

Basicamente ela calcula a proporção entre os valores "mínimo" e "máximo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente, não existe essa função padrão em Java, e provavelmente nem em C++, mas apenas no Arduino para a conversão dos valores dos sensores.

Você pode implementar ela no seu projeto por ser bem simples, e o código está no  link que você postou:

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

Comment: É verdade @George não tinha lido o post direito. Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos, sem problemas. É uma pergunta importante pra comunidade, ter uma função nativa seria muito mais simples mesmo!